# What is the Regular Expression for FF a b FF?

Tags: java, regex

What should be the regular expression for input like:

```
FF a b FF
```

where `a` and `b` can be of any combination as given below-

```
FF 1 2 FF
FF A C FF
FF F D3 FF
FF EF 1C FF
```

I have tried using `/(FF [a-zA-Z0-9] [a-zA-Z0-9] FF)/g`, but no match.

I have also tried `(FF .... FF)/g` it matches most of the entries (I don't know why as i am very new to this) and strings like `FF 2 0 FF` to `FF 2 F FF` are excluded in the match, again no idea.

input like: FF FF FF FF should be excluded from pattern matching.

Comment: what did you do so far and can `a` and `b` contain symbols or just a number of character and numbers

Comment: any insight on the downvote here? I am new to regex, i have never used it before and tried for hours to solve it. but no luck.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: are you using java or javascript as java do not require `/g` at the end and `/` at the start. Also `[a-zA-Z0-9]` will match a single character so you need to add `+` after it to accept one or more characters

Comment: I was testing with http://regexr.com/ provided online interface, as you pointed it out, it is actually for javascript i believe. Though I need to implement the regex in a java project to build a filter, Thanks to clarify on this.

Comment: `(FF [a-zA-Z0-9]* [a-zA-Z0-9]* FF)`

Comment: @Sonnet Please see my edit.

Comment: @Rakibul "input like FF FF FF FF should be excluded" what do you mean? What is "input like" that? What exactly differentiates valid from invalid input?

Comment: say, input 1: FF F D3 FF it should be counted as a match whereas input2: FF FF FF FF should not be counted as a match.

Comment: @Rakibul what is signficant about FF F D3 FF compared to FF FF FF FF such that the first is good and the latter is not? You are just giving another example. I want an explanation of what **differentiates valid from invalid input**.

Comment: not really, FF FF FF FF is a needed information here, say, FF F D3 FF | 1 2 3 4 4 6 7 FF FF FF FF |FF F 2 FF| 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 FF FF FF FF |FF 2 0 FF is written on a text file. (without the "|") I need to detect the pattern FF 2 FF FF or similar but not those FFs preceding it.

Comment: @Rakibul alright, it's not valid versus invalid; but you say one should be excluded from the pattern matching. Let me ask it one more time: what differentiates what you want matched from what you don't? (but I guess it hardly matters since you have accepted an answer already).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a and b are hex character(s), but not`FF`:

```
FF( (?!FF)[A-F0-9]{1,2}){2} FF
```

Basically, you needed in crease the allowed number of characters for a and b, either to a range like `{1,2}` (meaning 1 to 2), or just a plus sign `+` (meaning "one or more").

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/uE4sWsoicP).

Comment: is this applicable in java? i have tested it with regexr.com and it fulfills the requirement, and i missed a thing here, the middle two bytes are FF FF then it should be excluded in the pattern matching, can we achieve that?

Comment: i got an idea of filtering the pattern based on this answer. Thanks for the demo link and explanation.

Comment: @Rakibul I have updated both regex and link to exclude `FF` for a and b. `(?!...)` is a "negative look ahead", which asserts that what immediately follows does *not* match its pattern.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done
`^FF(?: [\\w\\d]+){2} FF$` where the expression checks that the string starts and ends with `FF` and in between there are exactly two words containing characters or numbers.